# Set or Remove UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance key introduced by react-native init

Tags: ios, react-native

According to [this site](https://github.com/jhabdas/react-native-webpack-starter-kit), the command `react-native init` does not set the correct value of the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` IOS key. Furthermore the site states that failure to do so leads to Apple Store rejection. How do I set the correct value or remove the key altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how this could lead to a rejection as Apple explicitly states that it is an option that you can turn on or off based on your preference:

> NOTE
>   If you prefer to opt out of having view controllers adjust the status bar style—and instead set the status bar style by using the UIApplicationstatusBarStyle method—add the UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance key to an app’s Info.plist file and give it the value NO.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html

Comment: There is more discussion on this at https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6892#issuecomment-208626027.

Answer (score -1):

Change 'UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance' into 'View controller-based status bar appearance' in the Info.Plist and that will fix the issue.